# How do I make a blur effect like a profile site on twitter?

Tags: xcode, animation, uiscrollview, blur

I am wondering how I can make a blur effect when I drag to the top of a UIScrollview like on twitter and in tweetbot. I have been looking around but I did not find it out anywhere. I know I have to use gaussian blur, but I don't know how I am going to implement it. Any code would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Twitter]

[image: Tweetbot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a project like you are looking for.

1. https://github.com/sibahota059/TwitterProfilePageBlurr
2. https://github.com/lostincode/kickstarter-pulldown-bouncy

You need to add the blurr effect while Scrolling.

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
// Add Blurr effect here.
}
```

Some similar Controls:

1. http://rowboatrevolution.com/2012/02/uitableview-parallax-background-a-la-path/
2. https://github.com/Rheeseyb/RBParallaxTableViewController

Comment: thank you very much! one question more: what should my void be if my scrollview is already named HypervenScroll, should it be : - (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)HypervenScroll ? because when I do this, my local declaration does not work inside the void...

Comment: You no need to take any scrollview. as UItable view itself a subview of Scrollview.

Answer (score 4):

I took a crack at this myself, using autolayout. The code is on [Github](https://github.com/benpackard/BENTweetbotHeader) and [here](http://cocoacovers.com/blog/2014/03/31/the-zooming-blurring-profile-photo-by-tweetbot/) is a walk through.

[tweetbot http://cocoacovers.com/images/1/final.gif](http://cocoacovers.com/images/1/final.gif)

Comment: Using a "clear" and "blurry" channel while adjusting the alpha of the "clear" channel is a great approach. Initially I was trying to render a continuous blur, but it was too taxing. Nice stuff!